# Form submit() not working in firefox but is working in chrome?

Tags: javascript

Why is this not working in `Firefox`, but is working in `Chrome`?

```
<script>
var newValue = 'test';

var f = document.createElement('form');
f.setAttribute('method','GET');
f.setAttribute('action','/test');

var customContext = document.createElement('input');
customContext.setAttribute('type','text');
customContext.setAttribute('name','CUSTOM_CONTEXT');
customContext.value = newValue;

var s = document.createElement('input'); //input element, Submit button
s.setAttribute('type','submit');
s.setAttribute('value','Submit');

f.appendChild(customContext);
f.appendChild(s);

f.submit();
</script>
```

Comment: any errors thrown? `newValue` is not defined in code shown

Comment: `newValue` was passed in via function, i've hardcoded a value for now. No errors seen in console.

Comment: It could be related to the fact that the form is not actually in the DOM. Try appending the form to the `body` and see the difference. You can also set the field to be `type="hidden"` so the addition should not be visible.

Comment: a lot of code that could be replaced by `location.href='/test?CUSTOM_CONTEXT='+encodeURIComponent(newValue);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Boaz ..

```
It could be related to the fact that the form is not actually in the DOM. 
Try appending the form to the body and see the difference. 
You can also set the field to be type="hidden" so the addition should not be visible
```